# is there any alternatives to JArchitect?

Tags: jakarta-ee, analytics

I've found JArchitect very good tool to perform J2EE application analytics, but it's little pricey, is there any free/open source alternatives to JArchitect?

Comment: answering my own question: **Structure** 101 in another great option (paid)

Answer (score 4):

- [STAN4J](http://stan4j.com/) is a Eclipse-based structure analysis tool for Java
- [Atlas](http://www.ensoftcorp.com/atlas/) is another static analysis tool for Java that integrates into Eclipse.  I helped teach a software class where students used Atlas to implement software metrics for Efferent and Afferent coupling.

Comment: Java 8 support with STAN 2.1.2, great!

Comment: Guys I'm trying to use stan with Eclipse-neon, but is not working, it's not in Run As.. menu. Any idea?

Comment: try using sourcetrail tool which is more similar tool